# PHP Overflow Modulus

Tags: php, overflow, modulus

I am writing an algorithm that uses successive squaring to solve a^k mod m.  Because of the way successive squaring works, the maximum number that the algorithm will ever have to compute is 2147483646^2 (I limited the user input to 214738364).  Unfortunately, it still has to compute this.  It seems to get the squaring part right, and then turns the overflowing number into a float, but then can't compute the modulus of a float and an integer.

A sample line is:

```
3422422^2 mod 715924 = 661224^2 mod 715924 = 437217178176 mod 715924 = -354280
```

How can I fix this, and how does one find one's way around integer overflow in PHP?

Comment: How can you fix what? That floating-point/integral mod isn't available?

Comment: Well, obviously a modulo isn't going to return a negative number, yet that is what's occurring here.  Is there a special PHP function for the modulus of a float and an integer?

Comment: [What's wrong with modulus returning a negative number?](http://codepad.org/TwoMrkOR) I don't think floating-point has anything to do with it; it's just an overflowed integer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the modulus of two positive integers won't return a negative number, as in the example I showed.  So what's happening here?  I thought that as soon as an integer overflowed in PHP, its type was changed to a floating point number.  So after 661224^2 overflow, 4372178176 becomes a float, and then it's trying to compute the modulus of a positive float and a positive integer.

Comment: I see. I can neither confirm nor deny that, but I'd be surprised. And I certainly wouldn't expect floating-vs-int mod to randomly give you a negative number.

Comment: [Seems you're right!](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) Then I have no idea what's going on here :)

Comment: Ah, perhaps the operand is getting converted to `int`. And then, from the manual: `If the float is beyond the boundaries of integer (usually +/- 2.15e+9 = 2^31 on 32-bit platforms and +/- 9.22e+18 = 2^63 on 64-bit platforms), the result is undefined, since the float doesn't have enough precision to give an exact integer result. No warning, not even a notice will be issued when this happens!` Really, trying to deal with huge values like this with primitives is a fool's errand. At _best_ you're going to have terrible precision and useless results.

Comment: I doubt that's easy to reimplement with a productive runtime behaviour (you'd need to work on strings and simulate integer arithmentic). Which is why [`bcpowmod()`](http://php.net/bcpowmod) exists.

Comment: That bcpowmod() worked like a charm, you should post it as an answer!  Two questions though.  First, if the result is undefined, why is the correct answer showing up?  And second, am I just going to have to find creative workarounds for integer overflow like that one, or is there one concrete way to go around it?  Because another algorithm I'm working on solves linear congruences, but it often overflows by multiplying two large integers together.  i.e.

2291255x = 47 mod 3106907
Multiply by 1882971.
4314366718605x = 88499637 mod 3106907

Cast out 3106907s
-3106906x = 1506241 mod 3106907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking out the [GMP extension](https://www.php.net/gmp) and reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391/arithmetic-with-arbitrarily-large-integers-in-php).