# PHP Sum of two numbers resulting in a large numbers with a + symbol

Tags: php, integer, multiplication

Sorry for not using the correct terminology, the fact is I don't know what you'd call this sort of number so it's making it incredibly difficult to Google.

I want to multiply two numbers together and get the result back as just numbers, but I keep getting a string looking like this: float(8.6135096694932E+15). I need to export this in an XML file so I need a string containing just the numbers not this weird response I am currently getting.

Here is a very simple example:

```
var_dump(2005489*4294967297)
//Actual Result: float(8.6135096694932E+15)
//Desired Result: 8613509669493233
```

My question is simply. How can I multiple those two numbers together and get the desired result listed above?

For a bit more context of what i'm trying to do: I am given an ID, in this instance "2005489" and I need to generate a new ID based on a fermat numbering system, which basically seems to mean that it must be multiplied by "4294967297", I do not fully understand why since I am interacting with third party software. It seems simple enough, but I need to actually be able to print the string "8613509669493233" in an XML file, not the weird response i'm actually getting.

EDIT 2:
Found another solution, very simple:

```
number_format($number, 0, '', '');
```

Found here: [Convert exponential to a whole number in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964059/convert-exponential-to-a-whole-number-in-php)

EDIT:
This has been marked as duplicate of this: [Arithmetic with Arbitrarily Large Integers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391/arithmetic-with-arbitrarily-large-integers-in-php)

However I cannot see how that offers a solution. The only example is:

```
gmp_strval(gmp_init($n, 10), 2);
```

However this does not offer any resolution, here is an example:

```
$number = (string)(2005489*4294967297);
$response = gmp_strval(gmp_init($number, 10), 2);
var_dump($response);
//0
```

Not using (string) results in:

> gmp_init(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Comment: I don't see how the supposed duplicate offers a solution?

Comment: Why using var_dump? Try print or echo

Comment: Echo has the same outcome